# postgres C:: Permission denied using windows

Tags: windows, postgresql, psql, postgresql-13

I am using Windows 10

I have a PostgreSQL file when I run inside the PSQL CMD

\i FILENAMEPATH

```
postgres=# \i C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\Projects\Movies\solution.sql
C:: Permission denied
```

I get that Permission Denied

C:: Permission denied

Is there a way around this? Or how can I gain permission?

Comment: Try forward slashes `\i c:/Users/Asus/Desktop/Projects/Movies/solution.sql`

Comment: I encountered the same problem, but after spending an hour searching the web, I stumbled upon your comment and your solution worked perfectly for me. Thank you so much for sharing! @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 14):

As [a_horse_with_no_name](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name) pointed out, using `forward slashes` instead of backslashes in the address solves the problem.

This is because windows unlike most OSs, resolves paths with forward slashes.

Comment: i still see the same error despite using forward slashes :/

Answer (score 0):

What solved this issue for me is opening a PowerShell in the folder location of the sql file (in folder: shift + right-click -> open PowerShell here), to avoid having to provide a file path, and then running '\i filename.sql'

Answer (score 0):

In my situation, when attempting to execute the initdb command, I encountered a permission denied error. To resolve this issue, I created a folder within my account's directory, and then the command executed successfully.

```
PS D:\Software\PostgreSQL\bin> .\pg_ctl initdb  -D "C:\Users\(my user name)\postgresql_data"
```